# How to identify the vector classes which override from different child classes?

Tags: c++, c++11, overriding

I would like to identify which child classes initialize pointers in a vector.

I prepare a vector that contains different types of override classes. After that, I set it as an argument in the same function. In the function, I would like to identify which classes initialize this argument and apply different processes for each class.

This is the code and current output.

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Parent
{
public:
    Parent() {};
    virtual ~Parent() {};

    virtual void print() 
    {
        std::cout << "I am parent!" << std::endl;
    }

};


class ChildA : public Parent
{
public:
    ChildA() {};
    ~ChildA() {};

    void print() override
    {
        std::cout << "I am child A!" << std::endl;
    }

};

class ChildB : public Parent
{
public:
    ChildB() {};
    ~ChildB() {};

    void print() override
    {
        std::cout << "I am child B!" << std::endl;
    }
};

void func(std::unique_ptr<Parent>& pa)
{
    pa->print();

    //if (pa is initialized from Parent)
    //{
    //}

    //if (pa is initialized from ChildA)
    //{
    //}

    //if (pa is initialized from ChildB)
    //{ 
    //}

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Parent> pa = std::make_unique<Parent>();
    std::unique_ptr<ChildA> chA = std::make_unique<ChildA>();
    std::unique_ptr<ChildB> chB = std::make_unique<ChildB>();


    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>> mList;
    mList.push_back(std::move(pa));
    mList.push_back(std::move(chA));
    mList.push_back(std::move(chB));

    for (auto& l : mList)
        func(l);

    return 0;
}
```

output

```
I am parent!
I am child A!
I am child B!
```

Could you tell me any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: Technically it's possible, but it usually means bad design. Why you cannot delegate such functionality to a virtual member function, which will be overridden in child classes?

Comment: This is because I have to rewrite a lot of parts in my code, but you are right. I should rewrite it as you said. Thank you!

Comment: The mechanism that enables checking dynamic type is called RunTime Type Informaformation (RTTI) and for `unique_ptr` you would have to use `get()` method to extract raw pointer and then `dynamic_cast`. But you should avoid it if possible.

Comment: I am changing a file structure following your first comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of doing polymorphic code with virtual functions is usually so you can avoid doing "is this an X" style tests. Instead you create a virtual function `doSpecialStuff` in the base class and call it via a base class pointer (like `print` in your code), which then does the appropriate operations for each derived class.

If you really want to test the type, use `dynamic_cast`:

```
if(auto child_ptr=dynamic_cast<ChildA*>(pa.get())){
   child_ptr->child_A_function();
}
```